# ImportError: cannot import name JSONB, from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql

Tags: flask-sqlalchemy, importerror, postgresql-9.4, jsonb

I wrote a model which has code something like this.
But JsonB is not imported from postgres. I have no idea why its not happening. How do i make it work?

```
from sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql import JSONB
class DataTable(Base):
    sourceid = Column(Integer)
    extraInfo = Column(JSONB)
```

Version of Alchemy:
SQLAlchemy==0.9.3

Version of Postgres:
postgresql-9.4

ImportError: cannot import name JSONB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Support for Postgres was introduced in [SQL Alchemy 0.9.7](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_0_9/changelog/changelog_09.html#change-0.9.7-postgresql). You can upgrade your SQL Alchemy to the new version using `pip install SQLAlchemy --upgrade`

Comment: i installed pip install SQLAlchemy and my version changed to 0.9.9 and it is working fine now.